# UIScollViewにUIImageViewがaddSubviewされない

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

ScrollView + ImageView + PageControl　
でローテーションバナーのようなものを実装しています。

画像URLが配列に入っており、
配列個数分forで回してScrollViewにImageViewをaddsubviewしていますが、
なぜか画像が5つの場合、5つめの画像が表示されません。

全て同じ画像URLを指定しても5つめの表示がされないので、
画像URLに誤りはありません。

```
int imageCount = (int)[imageArray count];
[self settingPageControl:imageCount];//PageControlの設定
[self settingScrollView:imageCount]; //ScrollViewの設定

CGSize size = _scrollView.frame.size;

for (int i=0; i<imageCount; i++) {
    UIAsyncImageView *imageView = [[UIAsyncImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width*i, 0, size.width, size.height);
    NSDictionary* imageDic = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [imageView loadImage:[imageDic objectForKey:@"Image"]];//画像読み込み
    [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

それぞれのframeをログに出してみたところ、frame指定も問題ないので困っています。
なにかお力添え頂ければうれしいです。

```
2015-04-15 15:10:18.091  i:0
2015-04-15 15:10:18.091  imageView.frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 187}}
2015-04-15 15:10:18.110  i:1
2015-04-15 15:10:18.111  imageView.frame:{{320, 0}, {320, 187}}
2015-04-15 15:10:18.111  i:2
2015-04-15 15:10:18.112  imageView.frame:{{640, 0}, {320, 187}}
2015-04-15 15:10:18.112  i:3
2015-04-15 15:10:18.112  imageView.frame:{{960, 0}, {320, 187}}
2015-04-15 15:10:18.113  i:4
2015-04-15 15:10:18.113  imageView.frame:{{1280, 0}, {320, 187}}
```

Comment: scrollViewのcontentSizeをセットしたらどうなりますか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
[self settingScrollView:imageCount]; 
の中で、こんな感じで設定をしております。
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width*count, _scrollView.frame.size.height);

Comment: scrollViewの中にUIViewを一つだけ置いてそのビューの子供としてimageViewをaddSubViewしたらいかがでしょう?

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、ダメでした。

Comment: UIAsyncImageView にloadImageしているところを、UIImageViewとして普通に　imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png"];　としたところ5枚目も表示されました。。。どうやらUIAsyncImageViewに絡んでいるようです。

Comment: 一度に4つまでしか接続を受け付けないサーバから画像をダウンロードしているとか? もしくはiOSが同時接続数に制限をかけているとか?
UIAsyncImageViewの中の通信エラーイベント処理にブレークポイントを貼ってみるとどうでしょう?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
いろいろな線で調べてみたのですが、UIAsyncImageViewでは特にエラーになっておらず、原因特定できずにおります。ひとまずUIAsyncImageViewを使わずに実装することにいたしました。